# Nginx - how to redirect to a new url with or without trailing slash

Tags: nginx, redirect, url-rewriting

I have the following URL redirect in my Nginx server block:

```
location /news/ { return 301 https://example.com/blog/category/news; }
```

I want the above location rule to work for URLs with or without the trailing slash, eg:

- OK: https://example.com/news
- OK: https://example.com/news/

But not in this case:

- NOT OK: https://example.com/newsletter
- NOT OK: https://example.com/newsmaker

How to change my location redirect rule to reflect this requirement?

Comment: Either use a regular expression, or add the edge case as a separate `location = /news` block.

Comment: @RichardSmith I was trying to get some examples of the regular expression. Location = /news would mean duplicate entries for each URL. I am testing, for now, the following rewrite rule - `location ~ ^/news/?$` It seems to be ok. What do you think?

Comment: That regular expression will match your two URIs. Do you need to match other URIs such as `/news/foo`?

Comment: No, just /news and /news/, all other links will be taken care of by separate location blocks.